# Django-react native (axios) Request failed with status code 403 Post

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, redux, axios

I was doing put and post operations with axios in React Native before. But then I got the following error. I'm sending cookies in the headers, but it doesn't solve the problem. Help me please.

[image]

Comment: ``403`` --> unauthorize means you'r request is understand by server but it's unautherized you've to look for errors comming from server

Comment: how can i do it on nginx web server